# how to click on next and previous button generate 7 days dates using javascript?

Tags: javascript

i am working with highchart using angularjs and i am go wanna data in the charts using date wise in to period by 7-7 days to generate dates.so now i am first time on the page load generate **current date to previous 7 days date like for ex "06-10-2017" to "12-10-2017"** and show in the chart. 
now i have add new 2 button on the page **next and pre** like. so i want click on **pre** button i want **pre again 7 days dates like for ex => "29-09-2017" to "05-10-2017**".
again i am click on **pre button i want date generate like "22-09-2017" to "28-09-2017".** and i am now click **on next button then i want "29-09-2017" to "05-10-2017"**. i want to like this date generate using javascript but how can skip dates on click button i have no idea any one have the idea than please help me here below i have write this code for first 7 days dates generate.

this is my 2 button in the html =>

```
<button class="previous" onclick="GetPreviousWeek()">Previous Week</button>
<button class="next" onclick="GetNextWeek()" style="width: 110px;">Next Week</button>
```

this is my javascript code =>

```
var today = new Date();
var daysSorted = [];
var FDates = [];
var goBackDays = 7;

for (var i = 0; i < goBackDays; i++) {
    var newDate = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - i));
    daysSorted.push(newDate.getTime());
}


 daysSorted.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a - b;
})

daysSorted.filter(function (obj) {
    var d = new Date(obj);
    FDates.push(("0" + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + '-' + ("0" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + d.getFullYear())
})

console.log("DateArray => " + FDates);
```

using this code i am get like this o/p =>

```
"06-10-2017"
"07-10-2017"
"08-10-2017"
"09-10-2017"
"10-10-2017"
"11-10-2017"
"12-10-2017"
```

Comment: this is like a tongue twister...

Comment: @assembler but how i have not idea i am try goBackDays (7-7) click on pre button that time i am getting any dates

Comment: `var myDate = new Date(dateChoosen); myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() - 7)` ?

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze if you possible than  please suggest me little bit more with ex

Comment: I can't really see your question here. If you have a Date from which you now where to go just make a new Date Range with two Dates which have the range you need